# How to cluster mail subject lines to mail threads?

Tags: email, search, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

If I only have the **subject lines** of mails (no other headers) is there a good algorithm (or package) to cluster them into a set of "related messages"?

A mail with the subject

- `Our travel plans`

is probably related to

- `Re: Our travel plans` and
- `Re: Re: Our travel plans`.

So far so good, but there is also

- `AW: Our travel plans`
- `Fwd: Our travel plans`
- `Our travel plans (Forward)`

I want to **cluster** all of them together into one thread. Mails with subjects like `plans`, `Re: Our meeting` and so on should not be in that thread, of course. I could very well live a hierarchical result -- actually, I kind of like that, because I'd expect that the chance that mails with similar content would get "closer" to each other.

So, i have a lot of ideas: Suffix matching, Prefix trees, Levensthein distances, Q-Gram profiles -- maybe too many. Therefore I ask myself: "Did anyone do this already?"

Comment: Well, `Fwd:` etc. can easily be identified as stopwords. Once your removed them, your example is trivial. It's highly specialized (so not of scientific interest) but will likely work well.
As for finding the stopwords, just count the most frequent additions to subjects within the same thread.

Comment: In general though, the subject is a too short text for most techniques (TF-IDF etc.) to work really well.

Comment: I would like to confirm that if you have another thread called "Our vacation plans" or "Our spring travel plans" that you would NOT want those clustered "Our travel plans". If that is the case then I agree with the noise-word approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sequence comparisons, I use Open Refine (formerly Google Refine) to try out clustering algorithms to fine-tune and identify the algorithm to use.  It includes key collision (fingerprint, ngram & double-metaphone) and nearest neighbor (levenshtein distance & prediction by partial matching (PPM)).

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Once you have your data imported, just use facets to do your clustering.

Facet > Text facet > Cluster